# Display custom field value as a mailto: link

Tags: custom-field, links

I'm very confused with an "Email" custom field, how I can make it automatically clickable as "mailto:" link, inside a loop like this:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $mail = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mail', true);                                                                     
    if  ($mail) {
        echo the_title()."</br>",
        echo $mail;
    } /*... rest of the loop
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you did all the hard stuff, so you can try this:

```
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $mail = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mail', true);   
    if  ($mail) {
        echo '<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'">email me at '.$mail.'</a>';
    } 
 /* ... */
```

Comment: Thank you @peteroak, works great!. Only I had to adjust some changes with ["]: `echo "<a href=mailto:", $mail. ">", $mail."</a>";'`